# How to find JavaScript variable by its name

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to find JavaScript variable on the page (get it as an object) by its name? Variable name is available as a string constant.

Comment: See also later question with additional answers: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664282/javascript-refer-to-a-variable-using-a-string-containing-its-name

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
<script>
var a ="test";
alert(a);
alert(window["a"]);
alert(eval("a"));
</script>
```

Comment: Please don’t use `eval` for this.

Comment: What about non-global variables? Is there any other option but `eval`?

Comment: @mxro: In that situation, you'd want to use an [object property](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25529838/157247).

Answer (score 31):

All JS objects (which variables are) are available within their scope as named properties of their parent object. Where no explicit parent exists, it is implicitly the `window` object.

i.e.:

```
var x = 'abc';
alert(window['x']); //displays 'abc'
```

and for a complex object:

```
var x = {y:'abc'};
alert(x['y']); //displays 'abc'
```

and this can be chained:

```
var x = {y:'abc'};
alert(window['x']['y']); //displays 'abc'
```

Comment: that's only true for globally scoped variables - if the scope is function-level, there's no object which allows access to the lexical environment

Comment: Sure, but nothing helps you there. This assumes you can express the var as a dot notation construct.

Comment: If you need to do it within a function, the only solution is to put your vars in an objection, and access the object's keys, like this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109297/javascript-function-name-as-a-string-in-self-executing-function/4109730#4109730

Comment: @Juan - that wouldn't be function level scope though.

Comment: that's the point of my comment. You can't do it to local functions without eval.

Answer (score 6):

If you are wanting a variable that is declared in the global context, it is attached to the window object.  ex: window["variableName"].  All variables are a hash table value within their scope.

If you have to use dotted notation, then you will want to follow kennebec's suggestion, to navigate through the object hierarchy.  eval() can work as well, but is a more expensive operation than is probably needed.

Answer (score 5):

If it's a global variable, you can look it up by name on the global object, since global variables are properties of the global object. On browsers, there's a global variable that refers to the global object called `window`, so:

```
var name = "foo";
window.foo = 42;
alert(Number(window[name])); // 42
```

But global variables are a Bad Thing<sup>(tm)</sup>.

To do this without globals, use your own object:

```
var name = "foo";
var obj = {};
obj.foo = 42;
alert(Number(obj[name])); // 42
```

Both of the above work because in JavaScript, you can refer to an object property either with dot notation and a literal (`obj.foo`), or with bracketed notation and a string (`obj["foo"]`), and in the latter case, the string can be the result of any expression, including a variable lookup.

Comment: What about if `obj` would be the variable to be accessed (and not `obj.foo`) - would `eval` be the only option then?

Comment: @mxro: If `obj` were a global, you could use `window["obj"]`. If it weren't, then you'd have to use `eval`. But I wouldn't, I'd change my code to put `obj` in a container so I could just look it up in the normal way.

Comment: Yes, that sounds good. I think I initially created a variable in an `eval` statement, which then I could retrieve only through a second `eval` - but then changed the code that a container variable is created before the first `eval`; eliminating the need for the second `eval`.

Comment: @mxro: If you create a variable in an `eval`, you should be able to access it normally: `eval("var x = 42;"); console.log(x);` shows 42 in the console. (But there's almost never any reason to use `eval`.)

Comment: Wow, thanks, that's also useful. But you are right, not very clean, I agree!

Answer (score 4):

If your string references a 'deep' property of a global, like 'Yankee.console.format' you can step through the references:

```
String.prototype.deref= function(){
    // remove leading and trailing quotes and spaces
    var obj= this.replace(/(^[' "]+|[" ']+$)/g,'');

    var M= obj.match(/(^[\w\$]+(\.[\w\$]+)*)/);
    if(M){
        M= M[1].split('.');
        obj= window[M.shift()];
        while(obj && M.length) obj= obj[M.shift()];
    }   
    return obj || this;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var getVar = function (obj) {
    for(var key in this) {
        if(obj === this[key]) return key;
    }
};

foo = 'foo';

console.log( getVar(foo) ); // => 'foo'
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17432007/1250044

Comment: double `foo` do helps to follow

Comment: This will merely return the value of the first variable on the window that has the given value. I don't see the point in doing this as it won't tell you anything you don't already know.

Answer (score 2):

You could use eval()

Comment: never *ever* use eval where you don't have to

Comment: vote up. simple question deserves a simple answer. i'd go with eval() if I for whatever reason needed to look at the contents of a variable by its name.

Comment: A). what's not simple about window[foo]? B). speed and security don't concern you then? eval is toxic, seriously

Comment: @annakata - i see your point, and never meant to say this solution is better than yours. i'm just saying that eval -does- resolve the question asked.

Comment: I'd hate for anyone to think this was a competition - I really honestly don't downvote for that - and I accept that eval does technically solve the problem, but nonetheless eval is the nuclear option. It's better if you don't have to use it.

Comment: @Peter, it's not a competition, but most well versed JS developers avoid `eval` and `with` like the plague. It should be OK to express dislike towards your solution. I would never post eval as a solution, unless there was no other, or it was just too cumbersome

Comment: Indeed, the use of `eval` may give rise to a lot of security issues, but I think this is currently the only general solution -- if the function is not completely designed by yourself. Although I don't know the specific situations in which `eval` must be used, I think that as long as there is safety-related awareness before use, there is no need to exclude it.

Comment: Nobody has given a replacement for eval(name). All that repeated talk about window[name] is useless if you need to find the closest variable in scope, regardless whether it's a property of the global object, or in local scope, or in some closure below. How else to do that?