# How can I refer to a variable using a string containing its name?

Tags: javascript, syntax, variables

Is there a way to refer to a Javascript variable with a string that contains its name?

example:

```
var myText = 'hello world!';
var someString = 'myText';

//how to output myText value using someString?
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724857/how-to-find-javascript-variable-by-its-name

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use an `eval` to do it, though I try to avoid that sort of thing at all costs.

```
alert(eval(someString));
```

A better way, if you find yourself needing to do this, is to use a hash table.

```
var stuff = { myText: 'hello world!' };
var someString = 'myText';
alert( stuff[someString] );
```

Comment: if I'd rather use the window['varname']; approach, how would I do it using with an object?

`var obj = {'eleID':'varname'};

for (var key in obj) {
    window[obj[key]];
}`

This doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: I keep seeing people saying to avoid using eval for this and similar questions - but why?

Comment: @Tron mainly because you don't control someString, but you are letting it to run as though you did. It could be malicious, have coding errors, or other nightmare-inducing issues. Imagine someString were "while(1){}" or a script that sent data to a malicious server.

Answer (score 37):

If that variable is on the global scope, you can use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) on the global object:

```
var myText = 'hello world!';
var someString = 'myText';

alert(window[someString]);
```

Comment: Amazing answer saves the use of eval +1 wish i could + 10

Comment: So goOD! Thank you! This is what I was looking for! `eval()` worked for my main case, but I couldn't check if the variable I was using `eval()` to exercise was defined or not. `typeof window[event.data.lingua_target_content_var] !== 'undefined'` works when `eval()` threw an error!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is at the top level, `window[someString] === "hello world!"`.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, there is no standard for creating a 'Master Object', or any built-in method to access variables on the initial scope with a string reference that I am aware of.

However, if you are using JavaScript for web development on a browser, the `window` Object will give you complete access to your current scope. For example:

```
myVar = "This is my var"; 
if(myVar == window.myVar){
     /*
         This statement would return true
         Because both variables reference
         the same string;
     */
}
```

This method will allow you to reference any scope-variable WITHOUT making it a string, but you can also use a string as needed with the bracket (`[]`) Selectors.

```
window['myVar']
```

It is worth mentioning that keeping data as a variable directly on the current scope leaves it open to be re-defined by other scripts running. Your variable can be overwritten by function argument names, for loop variables, and simply by assigning a new value to that variable.

To overcome this, I suggest using an Object to store all relevant data to your application (Static And/Or OOP). Like this:

```
$myApp = {
     var1 : 'This is Var1',
     apply : function(){
          alert('Started!');
     }
}

//Referencing relative variables
alert($myApp.var1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `eval`:

```
var myText = 'hello world!';
var someString = 'myText';

eval('var theTextInMyText = ' + someString + ';');

alert(theTextInMyText);
```

The desire to do this at all usually is a "code smell". Perhaps there is a more elegant way...

Answer (score 0):

```
eval("alert(" + someString + ");");
```

would work.

Answer (score 0):

`eval` will do that:

```
var myText = 'hello world!!';
var someString = eval('myText');

document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = someString;
```

As [demonstrated here](http://jsbin.com/oyoqa).