# Javascript: Array name as string; Need it to reference the actual array

Tags: javascript, hyperion

I have to "get at" an array, but all I have is a string that matches the array name.  Obviously this kind of thing won't work, but it shows what I'm trying to do:

```
var arrayname = new Array(1, 2, 3);
var array = 'arrayname';

Alert(array[0]);
```

Of course, the example above yeilds 'a' instead of 1, like I'd need.

The background is that I'm working with a Hyperion Business Intelligence dashboard, where which array used, is determined by a substring of the button's name that was used to call it.

Comment: Where is the array referenced?  Is it a property of some object.  I hope you're not telling me that it's a global variable!

Comment: This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664282/javascript-refer-to-a-variable-using-a-string-containing-its-name

Comment: Thanks for the pageslap tymeJV :)  I did search, but the appropriate keywords eluded me, and the automatic results didn't have it.  It's pretty much my same question.  In my mockup, it looks like eval() is what I was looking for, but I need to put it into practice.  Thanks!

Comment: @epascarello they're trying to do operations with it and then assign a value to an existing object.  It is similar, but not a duplicate.

Comment: Don't use `eval`. It's just not needed. If this is a global variable, use the `window` solutions below. If not, then don't use a variable to store your Array. Use the variable to store and object, and have the object store the Array so that you can properly use a string to fetch it.

Comment: ...like alex23's solution

Comment: @EdwardD it is the same thing. `alert(window[array][0]);` There is about 50 dupes with the same question. I just picked one of them.

Comment: Not sure why people are so down on eval().  It seems to have something to do with whether or not my use is global or local.  It's a global function, but it's private to that function, fwiw.  eval() is working perfectly for my needs.  It may not be the correct solution, but I don't see it creating problems further down the line.  Again, this is not for web use, but for dashboarding within a business intelligence client that happens to have its own "take" on javascript. Don't know whom to mark as answered, since none of these will work within my environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's very simple.

```
var storage = {};
storage.arrayname = [1, 2, 3];
alert(storage["arrayname"].join(','));
```

Polluting the global namespace is strongly discouraged. I would strongly advise you to refrain from using the `window` object for this purpose. Read [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862665/what-does-it-mean-global-namespace-would-be-polluted) for more details.

Comment: I think this is similar to @pscoder's answer, but creates something other than window to use.  Still seems awkward and complicated for my purposes, but maybe I'll come back to it.

Comment: @EdwardD: It's neither awkward nor complicated. It's just a simple object, and is the proper solution. You can shorten it to `var obj = {arrayname: [1,2,3]};` Then access as `obj[array][0];`

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `window` object to retrieve it if it is defined in the window context.

```
var array = window["arrayname"]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Hyperion doesn't have a window or document I can call in their version of Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
array = window['arrayname'];
```