# javascript: how to call var by it's name string?

Tags: javascript, string, var

I have

```
var mean = 20;
var median = 30;
```

I have function that should get parameter of type string ('mean' / 'median'), and do something with the parallel var:

```
function compute(varNameAsString){
  return varNameAsString.toVariable() + 5;
}
```

how can I implement the toVariable?
I tried

```
varNameAsString.valueOf()
```

but it didn't work...

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/724857/526704

Answer (score 1):

*[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1664294/3213803)*

Use a hash table. Try this.

```
var values = { mean: 20, median: 30 };

function compute(varManeAsString){
  return values[varNameAsString] + 5;
}
```

That should work.

Of course, you could always use `eval`, but as the post I linked to says, the hash table is usually better.

Comment: No, the "hash table" would be the proper solution here. Can you make edit your code to reflect the OPs actual example?

Comment: Sure. I'll fix that now.

Comment: @Bergi, Sorry about that mistake. Please tell me is you see anything else that I should fix for this answer. I am not actually a huge user of javascript.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the update!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
return eval(varNameAsString) + 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `window[varNameAsString]`:

```
var mean = 20;
var median = 30;

function compute(varNameAsString){
  return window[varNameAsString] + 5;
} 

compute('median'); // Will output 35
```

Comment: …but only if those variables are global, which they shouldn't be.