# Creating a dynamic variable name in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var $geometryPointFields = $('[class*="Point"]', $panel),
    $geometryLineFields = $('[class*="Line"]', $panel),
    $geometryPolygonFields = $('[class*="Polygon"]', $panel);

function(geometry) {
    // geomtery is either Point, Line or Polygon
    ${'geometry'+geometry+'Fields'}.show() // ?
}
```

How do I do this? I can't or rather don't want to use `window[]` or `scope[]`.

Comment: Is `geometry` a string?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes its a string. So `$('geometry'+geometry+'Fields')` ?

Comment: @Xufox Yea, I don't know so just made it up for the example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript). You never need or want unknown variable names. Please use an object instead: `const geometries = {$geometryPointFields: $('[class*="Point"]', $panel), $geometryLineFields: $('[class*="Line"]', $panel), `…`}; console.log(geometries["geometry" + geometry + "Fields"].show());`.

Comment: Also: [Refer to a variable using a string containing its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1664282/4642212).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the three variables are all geometry fields, it would probably make the most sense to use an object rather than three standalone variables:

```
const geometryFields = {
  Point: $('[class*="Point"]', $panel),
  Line: $('[class*="Line"]', $panel),
  Polygon: $('[class*="Polygon"]', $panel)
};
```

Then you can access the property of the object with the `geometry` string:

```
function showGeom(classStr) {
  geometryFields[classStr].show();
}
```

If you *have* to use standalone variables, you could `eval`, but you really shouldn't `eval`:

```js
$geometryPointFields = $('.point');
function showGeom(classStr) {
  eval('$geometry' + classStr + 'Fields').show();
}
setTimeout(() => showGeom('Point'), 1500);
```

```css
.point { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="point">point</div>
```

Comment: It's appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Your variables are formed using jQuery selectors' response. Why don't you select and show the elements directly in the function?

```
function showElements(geometry) {
  $('[class*="' + geometry + '"]', $panel).show();
}
```

You just need to ensure that `$panel` is accessible in this function, and it should work fine.