# If an object is stored in an array is it possible to view/retrieve the object's name from the array?

Tags: javascript

**Background:** In the simplified data structure below accessing individual items and their properties is straightforward.  For example the value *Volkswagon* is easy to access.

```
let car = {};
let truck = {};

car.one = 'Volkswagon';
car.two = 'Toyota';

truck.one = 'Dakota';
truck.two = 'Tacoma';

let vehicleArray = [car, truck];

console.log(vehicleArray[0].one);  //Volkswagon
```

**Question:** However is it possible to access the name's of the objects that are stored in the array?  In this case the values *car* and *truck*.  I'm not sure how to get those out of the array.

The code below returns properties and values inside the object but not the object's name.

```
console.log(vehicleArray[0]); // { one: 'Volkswagon', two: 'Toyota' }
```

Comment: No. If a thing's name matters like that, don't use an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript, refer to a variable using a string containing its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664282/javascript-refer-to-a-variable-using-a-string-containing-its-name)

Comment: Those aren't the "names" of the objects; they're variables to which a reference has been assigned. The objects don't "know" the variables exist.

Comment: Indeed, to further what Pointy says consider: `var foo = { a: 1 }; var bar = foo;` should the name be `foo` or `bar`?

Comment: @JaredSmith Very interesting conundrum.  In that case bar.a will return 1.  But dang, but there is no way to pull foo out dynamically?  Time to think about a restructure.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Explain your use case in more detail

Comment: @stackedAndOverflowed can't do it with vars. Again, if you need to be able to refer to something dynamically by name, put it in an object: `var someObj = { foo: { a: 1 } }; var bar = 'foo'; someObj[bar].a === 1;`

Answer (score -1):

You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array like this to retrieve all the values:

```js
let car = {};
let truck = {};

car.one = 'Volkswagon';
car.two = 'Toyota';

truck.one = 'Dakota';
truck.two = 'Tacoma';

let vehicleArray = [car, truck];

vehicleArray.map(({ one, two }) => console.log(one, two))
```

Or could [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get a specific value:

```js
let car = {};
let truck = {};

car.one = 'Volkswagon';
car.two = 'Toyota';

truck.one = 'Dakota';
truck.two = 'Tacoma';

let vehicleArray = [car, truck];

console.log(vehicleArray.filter(item => item === truck)[0].one)
```

This works by checking the [object equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness). Since `truck` and `vehicleArray[1]` are referencing the same object.

Comment: This does not answer the question: OP wants to dynamically get the variable names e.g. *car* and *truck*.

Comment: Thanks @skovy but Jared Smith is correct.  I'm trying to pull out the values car and truck dynamically without knowing they are inside.

Comment: The question has always stated that he wanted to get the values car and truck.

Comment: What's the use case? Could you add a `type` or `name` attribute to `car` and `truck`?

Comment: Using map incorrectly. It is the wrong tool for the job when all you really want is forEach. Similarly `find()` would be more appropriate than `filter()`

Answer (score -2):

If an object is stored in an array is it possible to view/retrieve the object's name from the array? No you can not...

If you wrap your objects with the name and push them to array you can get the names back

```
let car = {};

let truck = {};

car.one = 'Volkswagon';

car.two = 'Toyota';

truck.one = 'Dakota';

truck.two = 'Tacoma';

vehicleArray = [{car}, {truck}];

vehicleArray.map(v => console.log(Object.keys(v)[0]));
```

Comment: Where is the explanation that details how this solves OP's issue? Your "guess" is meaningless by itself. Take a few minutes to read through [answer]

Comment: vehicleArray = [...car, ...truck ]; if u want add arat them use it