# Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In PHP you can do amazing/horrendous things like this:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = 3;
$name = 'a';
echo $$name;
// prints 1
```

Is there any way of doing something like this with Javascript?

E.g. if I have a `var name = 'the name of the variable';` can I get a reference to the variable with name `name`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Variable" variables in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript). The accepted answer there is better than the one here because it shows how to do it, but also _correctly warns that there's almost always a better way to do whatever it is you want to do_. See [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) on meta.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is it appropriate to use a semicolon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38823062/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-a-semicolon)

Answer (score 407, accepted):

Since ECMA-/Javascript is all about `Objects` and `Contexts` (which, are also somekind of Object), every variable is stored in a such called **Variable-** (or in case of a Function, **Activation Object**).

So if you create variables like this:

```
var a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 3;
```

In the **Global scope** (= NO function context), you implicitly write those variables into the **Global object** (= `window` in a browser).

Those can get accessed by using the "dot" or "bracket" notation:

```
var name = window.a;
```

or

```
var name = window['a'];
```

This only works for the global object in this particular instance, because the **Variable Object** of the **Global Object** is the `window` object itself. Within the Context of a function, you don't have direct access to the **Activation Object**. For instance:

```js
function foobar() {
  this.a = 1;
  this.b = 2;

  var name = window['a']; // === undefined
  console.log(name);
  name = this['a']; // === 1
  console.log(name);
}

new foobar();
```

`new` creates a new instance of a self-defined object (context). Without `new` the scope of the function would be also `global` (=window). This example would alert `undefined` and `1` respectively. If we would replace `this.a = 1; this.b = 2` with:

```
var a = 1,
    b = 2;
```

Both alert outputs would be undefined. In that scenario, the variables `a` and `b` would get stored in the Activation Object from `foobar`, which we cannot access (of course we could access those directly by calling `a` and `b`).

Comment: Another cool thing is that in this way you can add callback (start/end) for any global level function.

Comment: But what if my dynamic variable is local in a function? for example:

function boink() {
  var a = 1;
  // this will not work
  var dynamic = this['a'];
  // this also wont work
  var dynamic = ['a'];
}

Comment: @Kokodoko—because *this* isn't "context" or a reference to a function's execution context (there is no way to reference an execution context, it's forbidden by the ECMA-262). *this* is set by how a function is called (or by *bind*), it's just an Object that has nothing to do with the execution context in which it's accessible.

Comment: If you need to access nested properties check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable/30974910#30974910

Comment: pointed me in the right direction with the bracket notation. Was stuck thinking dot notation only.

Comment: okay cool! I have a question please, people say don t pollute the global scope, but in the same time this thread demonstrates that the global scope, at the end of the day, is just occuped by all the declared variables? I m a little confused, any hint would be great about this subject

Answer (score 168):

`eval` is one option.

```js
var a = 1;
var name = 'a';

document.write(eval(name)); // 1
```

**Warning:** Note that using the `eval()` function is not recommended if you don't know what you are doing, since it brings multiple security issues. Use something else unless absolutely necessary. See [the MDN page for eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) for more info.

Comment: No it shouldn't as eval is evil. Never use eval!

Comment: @EasyBB - if you're going to say never to use something, I't helpful to explain why. I have a situation in which I can't think of any other way to accomplish what I'm doing other than eval()

Comment: Eval poses a risk for attacks on end users and we'll it's not technically evil rather misunderstood and misused in a lost of cases. I've seen php responses which hold literal vars in it then use eval to run it. Though this shouldn't be used in this case as there are better methods. This question at hand eval should not be used at all as there are better methods overall and I'm sure a lot of us know this.

Comment: Via https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/ ---

"Let’s consider the arguments most frequently leveled against using eval:
1) It requires a compile and is therefore slow
2) What if a malicious script found its way into the eval argument?
3) It looks ugly
4) It inherits the execution context and this binding of the scope in which its invoked"

Comment: Here is how to create dynamic variables using eval: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13291766/5528600

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: Nothing at frontend can be secure, you can always swap JS to your own anytime, so eval is not that eval because you can always use read-only strings or freeze objects.

Answer (score 106):

You can use the window object to get at it .

```
window['myVar']
```

`window` has a reference to all global variables and global functions you are using.

Comment: And needless to say, this one is safer than eval().

Comment: the `window` is look like `state`. that realy helpfull.

Comment: But how about when I want to use a local varaible?

Comment: @BuSaeed Not sure I understand, if the variable is already local scope, can't you just refer it to it by name? You should probably ask a new question as this is an old question with a different meaning.

Answer (score 62):

Just don't know what a bad answer gets so many votes. It's quite easy answer but you make it complex.

```
// If you want to get article_count
// var article_count = 1000;
var type = 'article';
this[type+'_count'] = 1000;  // in a function we use "this";
alert(article_count);
```

Comment: "in a function we use `this`" - If you want to access a _global_ variable in this way, it is better to be explicit and use the `window` object, not `this`. `this` is ambiguous.

Comment: But **inside of a function** you cannot use `this`, or anything else, to access the variable `type` from your example, if you have its name in another variable: `function test(vname) { var type = 'article'; this[vname] = 'something else'; alert(type); }; test('type')` will show `article`, not `something else`. And that is what the "complex answer" explains.

Comment: This does not work. It outputs `undefined` to the alert box if you put it in a function and call it with an object (either with the `new` operator or with dot notation).

Comment: Works great inside of Express.js routes

Comment: Thanks @Terry, this works perfectly in Vue. When you have multiple data properties declared, and you want a method to decide which data property to target, you just pass the property name like this: 
`changeProperty(propertyName) {
this[propertyName] = 1;
}
`
`changeProperty("bar")`
`changeProperty("baz")`

Comment: This might work in Express.js or Vue, but the original question was about JavaScript, generally. And in the general JS landscape there are tons of scenarios where this idea won't work.

Not sure why the high number of upvotes...

Answer (score 33):

This is an example :

```
for(var i=0; i<=3; i++) {
    window['p'+i] = "hello " + i;
}

alert(p0); // hello 0
alert(p1); // hello 1
alert(p2); // hello 2
alert(p3); // hello 3
```

Another example :

```
var myVariable = 'coco';
window[myVariable] = 'riko';

alert(coco); // display : riko
```

So, the value "*coco*" of **myVariable** becomes a variable **coco**.

Because all the variables in the global scope are properties of the Window object.

Answer (score 29):

```
a = 'varname';
str = a+' = '+'123';
eval(str)
alert(varname);
```

Try this...

Answer (score 21):

In Javascript you can use the fact that all properties are key value pairs. jAndy already mentioned this but I don't think his answer show how it can be exploited.

Usually you are not trying to create a variable to hold a variable name but are trying to generate variable names and then use them. PHP does it with `$$var` notation but Javascript doesn't need to because property keys are interchangeable with array keys.

```
var id = "abc";
var mine = {};
mine[id] = 123;
console.log(mine.abc);
```

gives 123. Usually you want to construct the variable which is why there is the indirection so you can also do it the other way around.

```
var mine = {};
mine.abc = 123;
console.log(mine["a"+"bc"]);
```

Comment: var someJsonObj = {}; in a loop.... for(var i=0; i<=3; i++) {
    someJsonObj[i] = [];
}, but i can be anything. so dynamically generated variables, all sit inside someJsonObj for easy reference.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to use a global object like window or global (node), you can try something like this:

```
var obj = {};
obj['whatever'] = 'There\'s no need to store even more stuff in a global object.';

console.log(obj['whatever']);
```

Answer (score 7):

2019

#### TL;DR

- `eval` operator can run string expression in the context it called and return variables from that context;
- `literal object` theoretically can do that by write:`{[varName]}`, but it blocked by definition.

So I come across this question and everyone here just play around without bringing a real solution. but @Axel Heider has a good approaching.

The solution is `eval`.
almost most forgotten operator. ( think most one is `with()` )

`eval` operator can dynamically run expression in the context it called. and return the result of that expression. we can use that to dynamically return a  variable's value in function's context.

example:

```
function exmaple1(){
   var a = 1, b = 2, default = 3;
   var name = 'a';
   return eval(name)
}

example1() // return 1


function example2(option){
  var a = 1, b = 2, defaultValue = 3;

  switch(option){
    case 'a': name = 'a'; break;
    case 'b': name = 'b'; break;
    default: name = 'defaultValue';
  }
  return eval (name);
}

example2('a') // return 1
example2('b') // return 2
example2() // return 3
```

**Note that I always write explicitly the expression `eval` will run.
To avoid unnecessary surprises in the code. `eval` is very strong**
But I'm sure you know that already

BTW, if it was legal we could use `literal object` to capture the variable name and value, but we can’t combine computed property names and property value shorthand, sadly, is invalid

```
functopn example( varName ){
    var var1 = 'foo', var2 ='bar'

    var capture = {[varName]}

}

example('var1') //trow 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`
```

Comment: It's a fast solution, but it is a bad practice because it's not safe and decrease performance since the JS engine can't optimize that method.

Comment: "default" is a reserved word in JavaScript. You should not use it as a variable name

Answer (score 6):

I needed to draw multiple FormData on the fly and object way worked well

```
var forms = {}
```

Then in my loops whereever i needed to create a form data i used

```
forms["formdata"+counter]=new FormData();
forms["formdata"+counter].append(var_name, var_value);
```

Comment: Thanks...It totally saved me ! 
this.$refs['listView' + index].nativeView.animate({..})
I needed vars inside refs like this.$refs.listView1 listView2 and so on...

Answer (score 3):

This is an alternative for those who need to export a dynamically named variable

```
export {
  [someVariable]: 'some value',
  [anotherVariable]: 'another value',
}

// then.... import from another file like this:
import * as vars from './some-file'
```

Another alternative is to simply create an object whose keys are named dynamically

```
const vars = { [someVariable]: 1, [otherVariable]: 2 };

// consume it like this
vars[someVariable];
```

Comment: Why do you need to `import`/`export` to do that? Why not simply creating an object and accessing its properties? Also, it's **not** possible to export dynamic names, unless you export an object as default...

Answer (score 1):

use Object is great too.

```
var a=123
var b=234
var temp = {"a":a,"b":b}
console.log(temp["a"],temp["b"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this have an accepted answer I would like to add an observation:

In ES6 using `let` **doesn't work**:

```js
/*this is NOT working*/
let t = "skyBlue",
    m = "gold",
    b = "tomato";

let color = window["b"];
console.log(color);
```

However using `var` **works**

```js
/*this IS working*/
var t = "skyBlue",
    m = "gold",
    b = "tomato";

let color = window["b"];
console.log(color);
```

I hope this may be useful to some.

Comment: same applies to `const`

Comment: True. But you can create an object with the variables and select the variable from there: `const vars = { t, m, b }; console.log(vars['b'])`. Otherwise `eval` works too.

Comment: @FabianvonEllerts what is the purpose of your comment? This answer only aims to address the difference between block-level scope (`let` & `const`) and global (`window`) scope (`var` & `function`). Your comment has nothing to do with that and rather serves as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will do exactly what you done in php:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var ccc = 3;
var name = 'a';
console.log( window[name] ); // 1
```

Comment: use a global scope - is bad idea, imho

Answer (score 1):

**Simplest** solution : Create an **array of objects** that every object has two field (variableName,variableValue)

```
let allVariables = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    allVariables.push({ variableName: 'variable' + i, variableValue: i * 10 });

for (let i = 0; i < allVariables.length; i++)
    console.log(allVariables[i].variableName + ' is ' + allVariables[i].variableValue);
```

OutPut :

```
variable0 is 0
variable1 is 10
variable2 is 20
variable3 is 30
variable4 is 40
```

console.log(allVariables) json :

```
 [
    {
        "variableName": "variable0",
        "variableValue": 0
    },
    {
        "variableName": "variable1",
        "variableValue": 10
    },
    {
        "variableName": "variable2",
        "variableValue": 20
    },
    {
        "variableName": "variable3",
        "variableValue": 30
    },
    {
        "variableName": "variable4",
        "variableValue": 40
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

what they mean is no, you can't.
there is no way to get it done.
so it was possible you could do something like this

```
function create(obj, const){
// where obj is an object and const is a variable name
function const () {}

const.prototype.myProperty = property_value;
// .. more prototype

return new const();

}
```

having a create function just like the one implemented in ECMAScript 5.

Comment: Beware: const is a keyword in ES6

Comment: ...and prior to that was a *future reserved word*.

Comment: there is `eval` operator

Answer (score 0):

eval() did not work in my tests. But adding new JavaScript code to the DOM tree is possible. So here is a function that adds a new variable:

```
function createVariable(varName,varContent)
{
  var scriptStr = "var "+varName+"= \""+varContent+"\""

  var node_scriptCode = document.createTextNode( scriptStr )
  var node_script = document.createElement("script");
  node_script.type = "text/javascript"
  node_script.appendChild(node_scriptCode);

  var node_head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]
  node_head.appendChild(node_script);
}

createVariable("dynamicVar", "some content")
console.log(dynamicVar)
```

Comment: small improvement, it is better to use `var node_head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]` instead of ID, as no one gives an `id="head"` to `<head>` :-)

Comment: I do :)
But thanks, now I can finally remove this `id="head" thing

Comment: This just seems to be an overly complex way of creating a global variable?! (...and how does this answer the question?)

Comment: genius :) eval is the solution. Even if your code does not work

Answer (score -1):

It is always better to use create a namespace and declare a variable in it instead of adding it to the global object. We can also create a function to get and set the value

See the below code snippet:

```
//creating a namespace in which all the variables will be defined.
var myObjects={};

//function that will set the name property in the myObjects namespace
function setName(val){
  myObjects.Name=val;
}

//function that will return the name property in the myObjects namespace
function getName(){
  return myObjects.Name;
}

//now we can use it like:
  setName("kevin");
  var x = getName();
  var y = x;
  console.log(y)  //"kevin"
  var z = "y";
  console.log(z); //"y"
  console.log(eval(z)); //"kevin"
```

In this similar way, we can declare and use multiple variables. Although this will increase the line of code but the code will be more robust and less error-prone.