# Perform function directly on element instead of result of document.getElementbyId

Tags: javascript, html, devexpress

I have an element with an ID of `BaseGridView` in my HTML. If I call a function directly on it, everything works, but if I get that element via `document.getElementById()` my function call doesn't work.

For example:

```
BaseGridView.DoSomething();
```

Everything works fine for me.

But if I do this:

```
var hd = document.getElementById("HiddenforMainViewID");
var z = document.getElementById(hd.value);
z.DoSomething();
```

Nothing works and Firefox says "TypeError: z.DoSomething is not a function". The value of `hd` is `"BaseGridView"`, and z is an actual element.

Can someone please explain to me why this won't work?

EDIT:

Since there is confusion how this:

```
BaseGridView.DoSomething();
```

Can even work, I really have no clue. I'm using DevExpress and somehow it is able to do such things. I've been referring to [this example](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E164).

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any white space inside that value?

Comment: Do you happen to have a **variable** named `BaseGridView`?

Comment: The only way you could access a DOM element such as `BaseGridView` without calling `document.getElement*` is if you created the element with `new`, added it to the DOM and kept a reference to it.  Unless you explicitly did that, my guess is that `BaseGridView` is not the same as the DOM element you get.

Comment: @Teemu im sorry i am not very strong with javascript. I Called `alert(z);` and it resultet in [object HTMLTableElement] so i guessed it has the right object at hand. 
@JamesMontagne no i dont have. i edited my post regarding to this.

Comment: Actually it was my bad, just read your code too fast :  ). I've removed the comment.

Comment: @Teemu your delted comment brought me to the answere! i dont know how Devexpress does it but you were right, one time i use BaseGridView as Variable (working) and one time i get the actual Html Element (not working) 
So all i had to do is to get the variable via its name and call the function on that. (see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724857/how-to-find-javascript-variable-by-its-name))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"TypeError: z.DoSomething is not a function" and "z is an actual element" (that is, an instance of the `Element` class) means that there is no `DoSomething` method available in the `Element` class.

Comment: Correct. One time i used the variable BaseGridView which Devexpress somehow can provide there, and the other time i try to use the actual HTML Element. This cant work of course. 
I had to [get the variable by its name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920867/javascript-get-local-variable-dynamicly-by-name-string) - not the HTML-Element - and everything worked fine.

Comment: @Marguth Right, `getElementById` returns an instance of `Element` :)