# Creating Json with the given data in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have data like this:

```
var a = [Joe,Peter,12345,programmer];
var companies = [xyz,abc,def];
var xyz = [programmer,HR,Tester];
var abc= [HR,Tester];
var def = [programmer,HR,Tester];
```

I want to create Json data like this dynamically

```
var json = {
    "FirsName" : "Joe"
    "LastName" : "Peter"
    "Phone"    : "12345"
    "XYZ"      : "Checked"   // if the company has programmer it should give checked 
    "abc"      : "unchecked" // if the company has programmer it should give unchecked 
    "def"      : "checked"
}
```

Comment: And what is your question? And what have you tried already? Add any code you've tried to your "question".

Comment: I believe that I have interpreted your question correctly. See my answer below. Also, your example data is not valid JavaScript and you cannot reference variables by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create an array called companies that reference variable names* as they do not mean anything to the interpreter. Instead, create a mapping of companies.

```js
var data = [ 'Joe', 'Peter', '12345', 'programmer' ];

var companies = {
  'xyz' : [ 'programmer', 'HR','Tester' ],
  'abc' : [ 'HR', 'Tester' ],
  'def' : [ 'programmer', 'HR,Tester' ]
};

function create(empData) {
  var employee = {
    firstName : empData[0],
    lastName  : empData[1],
    phone     : empData[2]
  };
  
  var ocupation = empData[3];
  for (var company in companies) {
    employee[company] = companies[company].indexOf(ocupation) > -1 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked';
  }
  
  return employee;
}

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = JSON.stringify(create(data), undefined, '  ');
```

```css
body {
    white-space: pre;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

### Result

```
{
  "firstName": "Joe",
  "lastName": "Peter",
  "phone": "12345",
  "xyz": "checked",
  "abc": "unchecked",
  "def": "checked"
}
```

---

### Notes

* *If that array contains strings, as I assume that is what you are attempting to do, then this is not possible; but if you are referencing them by their variable reference, and not the string name, then you need to define the variables first.*

#### Not Valid

You cannot reference a variable without scope.

```
var companies = ["xyz", "abc", "def"];
var xyz = ["Programmer", "HR", "Tester"];
var abc = ["HR", "Tester"];
var def = ["Programmer", "HR", "Tester"];
```

#### Not Valid

You cannot reference a variable that has not been defined.

```
var companies = [xyz, abc, def];
var xyz = ["Programmer", "HR", "Tester"];
var abc = ["HR", "Tester"];
var def = ["Programmer", "HR", "Tester"];
```

#### Valid

This creates a 2-dimensional array, but you don't know which company you are referring to, because there is not object-key relationship.

```
var xyz = ["Programmer", "HR", "Tester"];
var abc = ["HR", "Tester"];
var def = ["Programmer", "HR", "Tester"];
var companies = [xyz, abc, def];
```

Comment: Hi Mr.Polywhirl I have a question I'm getting those companies list dynamically is there any solution for that?

Comment: If they were part of an object, then you could use the scope of said object to access them. Technically, that is what I did in my solution. Variables by themselves cannot be explicitly referenced by their "symbol" (The variable name you designated).

Comment: You could possibly reference them by the window object, this is bad. Stay away from global scope. Stay as local as possible. Check out closures. Here is a quote from a popular answer in regards to scoping. It seems to explain your situation: [*"All JS objects (which variables are) are available within their scope as named properties of their parent object. Where no explicit parent exists, it is implicitly the window object."*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/724923).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean exactly but the way I do it is like this:

```
var myJson = new Object();

myJson.FirsName= "Joe";
myJson.LastName= "Peter";
myJson.Phone= "12345";
myJson.XYZ= true;
myJson.abc= false;
myJson.def= true;

var jsonString= JSON.stringify(obj);
```

hope it's help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your data provided, I think you want to take decision that the array a designation matches with company array(s) values then it's value in JSON object should be true otherwise false.

If right, the following might be helpful:

```js
var a = ["Joe", "Peter", "12345", "Programmer"];
    var companies = ["xyz", "abc", "def"];
    var xyz = ["Programmer", "HR", "Tester"];
    var abc = ["HR", "Tester"];
    var def = ["Programmer", "HR", "Tester"];
    
    var jsonObject = new Object();
    
    jsonObject.FirsName = a[0];
    jsonObject.LastName = a[1];
    jsonObject.Phone = a[2];
    jsonObject.XYZ = xyz.indexOf(a[3]) > -1 ? true : false;
    jsonObject.abc = abc.indexOf(a[3]) > -1 ? true : false;
    jsonObject.def = def.indexOf(a[3]) > -1 ? true : false;;
    
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
    document.write(jsonString);
```

Comment: You didn't even use the `companies` variable. I think @Jquey007 needs to rethink their data model. See my response below.

Comment: I know, what is the use of company array if other three arrays have been created. This is just to create code-complications, nothing else.

Comment: No, I wasn't saying *you* had to, I was just waiting to see someone *not using it* to validate my point below.