# Jquery - this id as variable

Tags: jquery, variables

Sorry this isn't easy to explain..

When my script loads it reads some values to variables. eg:

```
enabled = $("#enabled").prop("checked") ? '1' : '';
local = $("#local").prop("checked") ? '1' : '';
senior = $("#senior").prop("checked") ? '1' : '';
```

Later in the script if a user has clicked on an element, I want to check if the selected element exists and is 1 or not.

```
$("body").on('change', '#enabled, #local, #senior', function() {
    var Check = $(this).attr('id')
```

Check returns enabled, local or senior.

How can I use that to get the value from the relevant variable called enabled, local or senior ?

Thanks

Comment: Are enabled, local and senior are global (window) variables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find JavaScript variable by its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724857/how-to-find-javascript-variable-by-its-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access variable value by passing variable name to window object:

```
window[Check]
```