# Javascript loop use variable from outside loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm trying to do a simple JS loop where I initialize a variable with a value outside the loop, but for some reason its not working.

Basically, I'd like to have `total_money` equals to `20` in my example, but it keeps returning `money`

```
var total = 0;
var money = 20;
var ticker = ['money'];
for (tick in ticker) {
  total_money = ticker[tick];
}

console.log(total_money);
```

Comment: `total_money = window[ticker[tick]];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find JavaScript variable by its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724857/how-to-find-javascript-variable-by-its-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single-quotes `'...'` from your array called ticker:

```
var total = 0;
var money = 20;
var ticker = [money]; // <-- Remove the single-quotes
for (tick in ticker) {
  total_money = ticker[tick];
}

console.log(total_money);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a simplified version of the code, but just be aware that you are not adding up total_money but overwriting

So if you have another ticker. For example:

```
var total = 0;
var money1 = 20;
var money2 = 30;
var ticker = [money1,money2];
for (tick in ticker) {
  total_money = ticker[tick];
}
```

console.log(total_money);

You will get total_money = 30, not 50.

You can fix this by doing `total_money += ticker[tick]`

Also note that you are looping through one item.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because:

```
for (tick in ticker) {
  console.log(tick) //tick equal 0
}
```