# Get value of variable by dynamic variable name

Tags: javascript

How can I get the value of variable `mjt_plan1` by using a dynamic variable `plan`?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var plan = 'plan1';
    var mjt_plan1 = '10000';
    alert('mjt_' + plan);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript)

Comment: try using `window['mjt_' + plan];`

Comment: tested both : your suggestion and checked provided link too , No result :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find JavaScript variable by its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724857/how-to-find-javascript-variable-by-its-name)

Answer (score 0):

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var plan = 'plan1';
        var mjt_plan1 = '10000';
        alert(window['mjt_' + plan]);
    });
```

Comment: better option than eval. use of window to get declared variable

Answer (score 0):

[How to find JavaScript variable by its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724857/how-to-find-javascript-variable-by-its-name)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var plan = 'plan1';
        var mjt_plan1 = '10000';
        alert (eval ('mjt_'+plan));

    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that [`eval()` can be dangerous and slow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!).