# How to access variable with dynamic name that stores an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, variables

I can't access the variable with a current name that has an index indicator dynamically

```
let arr = []
let var0 = {"key1": "a"}
let var1 = {"key1": "b"}

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  arr.push(var[i].key1)
}
```

My goal is to end with an array like this
arr = ["a", "b"]

Comment: Why not use an array for `var0` and `var1`?

Comment: keep an object. `const obj = {var0:{key1:'a'},var1:{key1:'b'}}` . then you can access like `obj['var'+i].key1`

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724857/how-to-find-javascript-variable-by-its-name

Comment: Because actually I'm testing a component that can make many requests... and for each request I'm storing the response within an variable. After that I need to access each variable to create another HTTP request using the response values. One for each different 'attribute'